# Angularjs get <td> index value in popup textbox

Tags: angularjs, arrays

in table i can get array of key value below mention code. it's working fine

**`get value`**

```
<tbody ng-repeat="value in ITR">
        <tr ng-repeat="(key, val) in value">
            <td>{{val.pan_number}}</td>
            <td>{{val.name}}</td>
            <td>{{val.tax_payable}}</td>
            <td>{{val.taxes_paid}}</td>
            <td>{{val.year}}</td>
            <td><button class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="open($index)">Edit</button></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
```

on edit i want to show all value in that popup textbox below  mention code
**`Controller.js`**

```
$scope.open = function(){
        var modalInstance = $uibModal.open({
            templateUrl: 'path.html',
             animation: true,
            controller: function($scope, $modalInstance) {
                $scope.cancel = function() {
                    $modalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
                };
                $scope.ok = function () {
                  $modalInstance.close();
                };
            }
        });
      }
```

**`popup.html`**

```
<div class="modal-content">
  <div class="modal-header">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" ng-click="cancel()" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
    <h4 class="modal-title">ITR Update</h4>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-body">
    <input type="text" name="pan" ng-model="val.pan_number"/>
    <input type="text" name="pan" ng-model="value.pan_number"/>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-footer">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="cancel()">No</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="ok()">Yes</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

But i can't able to get the value what mistake i done here. How to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can pass `val` from template and `resolve` that in modal controller as follows,

`<td><button class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="open(val)">Edit</button></td>`

```
$scope.open = function(val){
    var modalInstance = $uibModal.open({
        templateUrl: 'popup.html',
        animation: true,
        resolve: {
          value: function(){ return val; }
        },
        controller: function($scope, $modalInstance, value) {
            //to retain original value, we are making copy
            $scope.val = angular.copy(value);
            $scope.cancel = function() {
                $modalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
            };
            $scope.ok = function () {
              for(var k in $scope.val){
                 value[k] = $scope.val[k];
              }
              $modalInstance.close();
            };
        }
    });
  };

<!--popup.html-->

<div class="modal-content">
  <div class="modal-header">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" ng-click="cancel()" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
    <h4 class="modal-title">ITR Update</h4>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-body">
    <input type="text" name="pan" ng-model="val.pan_number"/>
    <input type="text" name="pan" ng-model="val.name"/>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-footer">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="cancel()">No</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="ok()">Yes</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

1. We are passing the object reference (`val`) directly to the modal. ie) `open(val)`
2. Using `resolve` we can pass `val` as dependency to modal controller
3. Since we are binding the value to `ng-model` - which actually updates the original `value` reference, if we directly using it without copy. So, we are making a copy of passed `value` and binding it to `ng-model`.
4. when user clicks `ok` - we update the modified value to original `value` reference.

Answer (score 0):

you need to pass the scope to the model controller using `scope: $scope`

```
$scope.open = function(){
        var modalInstance = $uibModal.open({
            templateUrl: 'path.html',
            scope: $scope, //passed current scope to the modal
            animation: true,
            controller: function($scope, $modalInstance) {
                $scope.cancel = function() {
                    $modalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
                };
                $scope.ok = function () {
                  $modalInstance.close();
                };
            }
        });
      }
```

Edited

or either you can create a service and call that service from the `resolve`. That way you can access the data from the controller. In order to do this you need to save the data in a service first before the model open

```
var modalInstance = $uibModal.open({
    templateUrl: 'path.html',
    scope: $scope, //passed current scope to the modal
    animation: true,
    resolve {
        getData: function(sampleService) {
            return sampleService.getData(); // return the nessasry data for your model
        }
    }
    controller: function($scope, $modalInstance, getData) {
        $scope.val = getData; // return the data
        $scope.cancel = function() {
            $modalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
        };
        $scope.ok = function() {
            $modalInstance.close();
        };
    }
});
```

Comment: you can always create a resolve and pass data to controller. Check the updated answer

Answer (score 0):

You're missing the parameter in the function:

```
$scope.open = function(index){
        var modalInstance = $uibModal.open({
            templateUrl: 'path.html',
            animation: true,
            resolve:{
                IndexValue:function(){return index;}
            }
            controller: function($scope, $modalInstance, IndexValue) {
                $scope.cancel = function() {
                    $modalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
                };
                $scope.ok = function () {
                  $modalInstance.close();
                };
                $scope.value = {
                    pan_number:IndexValue()
                }
                $scope.val = {
                    pan_number:IndexValue()
                }
          }
        });
      }
```

Comment: Still same not pass the value

Comment: Give it a try now.

Comment: No luck still textbox empty only not pass any value

Comment: how to get the valu in text box

Comment: You were not assigning the value passed in to your scope value.

Comment: IndexValue is not defined

Comment: That should do it.

Comment: after adding this i got this error  IndexValue is not defined